# When Ubuntu is used on a tablet will it function like a computer?

Tags: tablet

Is it possible to load Ubuntu for a full computer onto a tablet (not a tablet PC) so that I could use open office or other software that I could use in Ubuntu on a full computer on a tablet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm informed, yes. They will function closely the same.

I can't imagine, not being able to use Open Office. This I will almost guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has a very good touch-optimized interface (exception of menus: grrrr), so I don't see why not. You will probably need to enable the onscreen keyboard called Onboard, though.

Only issue I see is if it's running Windows RT, meaning that it's ARM based, which means virtually no Ubuntu support because of Secure Boot.

Comment: You can also use [Ubuntu GNOME](http://www.ubuntugnome.org), it's more touchscreenfriendly

Comment: @com.BOY Indeed, but I found that it eats a few more resources than Unity.

Comment: please give her a few points - she need 20 points for to be allowed to chat - thanks !

Comment: @dschinn1001 You upvote the question yourself, then

Comment: @YetAnotherUser Oh, really? In general people say Unity eats more resources

Comment: @com.BOY If the videocard driver isn't installed or doesn't exist, unity lags and glitches less (note: I was using fedora on an AMD APU without drivers on GNOME, and it was unusably glitchy)

Comment: @dschinn1001 done.